# Sticky footer with padding and margins - working in FF but issues with Chrome and IE

Tags: css

I am trying to implement a sticky footer for a site i'm working on ([see here](http://www.exstockbearings.co.uk)). I attempted to follow the guide on [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) - specifically, [this](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/Owlyfool/HTML5%20Boilerplate%20Sticky%20Footer%20With%20100%25%20wide%20centered%20header/footer%20CSS) implementation.

This is working perfectly in Firefox (13) but in Chrome (21) and IE (9) the #footer is pushed further down the page adding a vertical scroll bar. I assume this is something to do with the use of padding and margins inside my #wrapper - however I am unable to put my finger specifically on the issue. I would really appreciate some help.

The site structure:

```
<html>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="page"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</html>
```

and the relevant CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#header { 
background: url("/images/backgrounds/transparent.png") transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EF7C31;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    width: 960px;
}
#menu { 
background:#FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 920px;
}
#page {
background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px;
    width: 920px
}
#footer {
background: url("/images/backgrounds/transparent.png") transparent;
    border-top: 2px solid #EF7C31;
    clear: both;
    height: 116px;
    margin-top: -158px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please include the specific code in question here. We should not have to go view your site and weed through the entire site to help you solve one specific issue. It would also be helpful if you created a jsfiddle that only included the necessary code so it is easier to test recommended changes by people.

Comment: @JoshMein Thanks for the comment. I have added in the relevant code. I tried to create a jsfiddle but keep getting server not found fiddle.jshell.net on both Chrome and FF?

Comment: Have you checked out my solution? I have attached a live demo that includes content that will push the footer down out of site. You can then remove that content and see that it still sticks the footer to the bottom of the screen. I have checked it in IE, Firefox, and Chrome and it worked in all of them.

Comment: @JoshMein - yes I saw your comment thank you, however I am reluctant to add extra div's which dont have any semantic meaning (ie .push)

Comment: Thats a first. You could always rename it to pushFooterToBottom or something similar. :P

Comment: I mean how it has no on page meaning to the user - it holds no content. It just doesn't feel like a good design standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to the wrapper:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

So you would have:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively add a push div just before the footer. This will push the footer down.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry. Just testing it out. On a vertically long page, the content in #page is now pushed behind #footer (but it works perfectly on "short" pages with little content)

Comment: On #wrapper? I assume the issue stems from me incorrectly applying padding-bottom on #page

Comment: I see that the register page is affected

Comment: If you take the padding out altogether from page it achieves partial success. try it out and see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few things that were causing some issues. The tutorial you linked to is marked as malicious here at work so I have always used [Ryan Fait's CSS Sticky Footer Tutorial](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Checking what you have off of that I noticed a few differences. First of all, you need to set the html body and height as 100% for this to work in all browsers. Secondly, your padding and your border were causing issues, so I created another div that would contain the specific content within your footer and would have the padding and the border css included on it.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="page"></div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="footerContent"></div>
    </div>
</html>​
```

**CSS**:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto -158px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

#footer, .push {
    height: 158px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

.footerContent {
    border-top: 2px solid #EF7C31;
    padding:20px;
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vE4F4/7/)